# Android Error to reopen an alreay closed object

Tags: android, sql

I want to load some datas from DB, and i have a problem i don't understand.

My function :

```
public List<News> getNews(){
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    List<News> tmp_list = new LinkedList<News>();

    txtRequest = "SELECT * FROM myTable ";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(txtRequest, null);

    tmp_list = loadListNews(c);

    return tmp_list;    
}
```

After that, I call to the function "loadListNews" :

```
public List<News> loadListNews(Cursor c) {
    List<News> tmp_list = new LinkedList<News>();
    while(c.moveToNext()) { 
        tmp_list.add(loadOneNews(c));
    }
    return tmp_list;
}
```

And finally, I call this function to create my object news :

```
public News loadOneNews(Cursor c1) {
    c1.moveToFirst();
        // i'm creating my object
    c1.close(); 
    return tmpNews;
}
```

And with that, i have the error "Error to reopen an alreay closed object"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing the cursor after the first pass in your while loop.

Plus you are always moving to the first element of your SQL result thus potentially only reading the 1st one and creating an infinite loop. Luckily you have a close to stop your loop ;)

You could make the following small changes to improve it a little bit already:

```
public List<News> loadListNews(Cursor c) {
    List<News> tmp_list = new LinkedList<News>();
    c.moveToFirst()
    while(c.moveToNext()) { 
        tmp_list.add(loadOneNews(c));
    }
    c.close()
    return tmp_list;
}

public News loadOneNews(Cursor c1) {

   // i'm creating my object

    return tmpNews;
}
```

Comment: i not agree, because i close an other cursor, not the same, no ?

Comment: i don't understand why.. it's a local cursor in my function loadOneNews, not the same ?

Comment: You are not cloning the cursor plus why would you want to do that anyway? the cursor is passed as an argument and it is not an immutable  object.

Answer (score 1):

Close cursor after using, not in while loop execution (on loadListNews).

```
public List<News> loadListNews(Cursor c) {
    List<News> tmp_list = new LinkedList<News>();
    while(c.moveToNext()) { 
        tmp_list.add(loadOneNews(c));
    }
    c.close();
    return tmp_list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because in your `loadOneNews` you `close` the cursor so after you do the first one you cannot access the cursor because you closed it

what you really want is to close it after you loop through all the rows

```
if(c.moveToFirst()){

    do{
        tmp_list.add(loadOneNews(c));
    }while(c.moveToNext()) { 

    c.close();
}
```

Comment: as i said below i don't understand... the cursor in "loadOneNews" is a local cursor, not the same that i'm using in loadListNews, no ?

Comment: no it is not a local cursor, it is still pointing back to the original cursor object

Comment: ok ok.. i did that, but it's not running, it seems to enter in a infinite loop :/

Comment: you need to remove the call to `moveToFirst` in your `loadOneNews`